# Hello, how do I read a pdf file from assets using widget.RecyclerView?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to kotlin, how do I write the code correctly? I searched for a long time, but I didn't find anything. I can't figure out how to write the parcel.(), to open a pdf file from the list in the app on phone.

my activity kt

```
class lab1 : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var dataList: ArrayList<labdataclass1>
    lateinit var imageList: Array<Int>
    lateinit var titleList: Array<String>
    lateinit var descList: Array<String>
    lateinit var detailImageList: Array<Int>
    private lateinit var myAdapter: labadapterclass1
    private lateinit var searchView: SearchView
    private lateinit var searchList: ArrayList<labdataclass1>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.lab1)

        supportActionBar?.hide()


        imageList = arrayOf(
            R.drawable.one,
            )

        titleList = arrayOf(
            "Перемещение холста \n" +
                    "в inkscape",
            )

        descList = arrayOf(
            getString(R.string.lab2lection1)
            )

        detailImageList = arrayOf(
            R.drawable.l2a1b
            )

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        searchView = findViewById(R.id.search)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)

        dataList = arrayListOf<labdataclass1>()
        searchList = arrayListOf<labdataclass1>()
        getData()

        searchView.clearFocus()
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                searchView.clearFocus()
                return true
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                searchList.clear()
                val searchText = newText!!.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                if (searchText.isNotEmpty()){
                    dataList.forEach{
                        if (it.dataTitle.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(searchText)){
                            searchList.add(it)
                        }
                    }
                    recyclerView.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                } else{
                    searchList.clear()
                    searchList.addAll(dataList)
                    recyclerView.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
                return false
            }

        })

        myAdapter = labadapterclass1(searchList)
        recyclerView.adapter = myAdapter

        myAdapter.onItemClick = {
            val intent = Intent(this, labdetailactivity1::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("android", it)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

    }

    private fun getData(){
        for (i in imageList.indices){
            val dataClass = labdataclass1(imageList[i], titleList[i], descList[i],detailImageList[i])
            dataList.add(dataClass)
        }
        searchList.addAll(dataList)
        recyclerView.adapter = labadapterclass1(searchList)
    }
}
```

my dataclass kt

```
data class labdataclass1(var dataImage:Int, var dataTitle:String, var dataDesc: String, var dataDetailImage: Int): Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        parcel.readInt(),
        parcel.readString()!!,
        parcel.readString()!!,
        parcel.readInt(),

    ) {
    }
    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeInt(dataImage)
        parcel.writeString(dataTitle)
        parcel.writeString(dataDesc)
        parcel.writeInt(dataDetailImage)

    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<labdataclass1> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): labdataclass1 {
            return labdataclass1(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<labdataclass1?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

my detailactivity kt

```
class labdetailactivity1 : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_labdetailactivity1)

        supportActionBar?.hide()

        val getData = intent.getParcelableExtra<labdataclass1>("android")
        if (getData != null) {
            val detailTitle: TextView = findViewById(R.id.detailTitle)
            val detailDesk: TextView = findViewById(R.id.detailDesk)
            val detailImage: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.detailImage)

            detailTitle.text = getData.dataTitle
            detailDesk.text = getData.dataDesc
            detailImage.setImageResource(getData.dataDetailImage)

        }
    }
}
```

my adapterclass kt

```
class labadapterclass1 (private  val dataList: ArrayList<labdataclass1>): RecyclerView.Adapter<labadapterclass1.ViewHolderClass>(){

var onItemClick: ((labdataclass1)-> Unit)? = null

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolderClass {
    val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.labitem1,parent, false)
    return ViewHolderClass(itemView)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolderClass, position: Int) {
    val currentItem = dataList[position]
    holder.rvImage.setImageResource(currentItem.dataImage)
    holder.rvTitle.text = currentItem.dataTitle

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{
        onItemClick?.invoke(currentItem)
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return dataList.size
}

class ViewHolderClass(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val rvImage: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.listImage)
    val rvTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.listName)
}
```

}

my activity xml

```
<

?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
    android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".lab1">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:id="@+id/search"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        app:searchHintIcon="@null"
        app:queryHint="Поиск..."
        android:focusable="false"
        app:closeIcon="@drawable/baseline_clear_24"
        app:searchIcon="@drawable/baseline_search_24"
        android:background="@drawable/search_bkg"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_dashboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.011" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

my activityitem xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
    android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/listImage"
            android:src="@drawable/one"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listName"
            android:text="@string/textbook1"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/listImage"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I found enough information on how to open a pdf file from the phone's storage, but I did not find information on how to open a pdf file from assets using the list. I will be very grateful for your help.
I'm new to kotlin, sorry I can't explain it properly. My application should have a list with names (clickable) that will open pdf documents from assets. I uploaded a pdf document to assets under the name pr1.pdf. I wanted to implement the opening of pr1.pdf through a list (there will be 30 lines in the list, each of which will open a pdf file uploaded to assets). This means that then I will add the rest of the pdf documents (pr2.pdf, pr3.pdf.... pr30.pdf) There will also be a SearchView search engine (it will search by names from the list). In my code, the names from the list are "titleList". I am using a list, and I wanted to open the PDF file data using each element of the list (item 1,2,3...), when clicked, so that the pdf document opens immediately. At the moment, the code implements the opening of the title, photo, and long text.(that is, there is a list on the activity, when you click on one block from the list, subsequent information opens).  I just wanted to replace this data with a simple pdf file opening, but I don't understand how to figure out the syntax, how to implement it correctly in the code.

Comment: That has nothing to do with a view or a recycle view. To read a file from assets you ask the assets manager to give you an input stream for the file. Then you read from the stream. Pdf has nothing to do with it either. You can do this for all files.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Do you want to just open the PDF file data or parse/render the PDF files? Android has no built-in support for parsing or rendering PDF files. You need to use a third party library.

Comment: I am using a list, and I wanted to open the PDF file data using each element of the list (item 1,2,3...), when clicked, so that the pdf document opens immediately. At the moment, the code implements the opening of the title, photo, and long text.(that is, there is a list on the activity, when you click on one block from the list, subsequent information opens). I just wanted to replace this data with a simple pdf file opening, but I don't understand how to figure out the syntax, how to implement it correctly in the code.

Comment: Sorry, you explained nothing. You did not even mention assets and who should display the pdf. Nor did you tell where all the info in the views comes from.

Comment: `a simple pdf file opening` By your app? Or another app? You did not tell what you want.

Comment: I'm new to kotlin, sorry I can't explain it properly. My application should have a list with names (clickable) that will open pdf documents from assets. I uploaded a pdf document to assets under the name pr1.pdf. I wanted to implement the opening of pr1.pdf through a list (there will be 30 lines in the list, each of which will open a pdf file uploaded to assets). This means that then I will add the rest of the pdf documents (pr2.pdf, pr3.pdf.... pr30.pdf) There will also be a SearchView search engine (it will search by names from the list). In my code, the names from the list are "titleList".

Comment: I will add my full code to the question